# LAN not working properly from one specific device

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, lan

I have a Nexus S running cm10, which can connect without problems to the internal LAN. However my Nexus One running cm7, for reasons that are completely beyond me, fail to connect to it.

I'm totally clueless, I have no idea where I could investigate any more:

- it is connected to the internet via Wifi, and access to the Internet works
- access to the LAN, i.e. 192.168.1.0/24 addresses, doesn't
- except that it correctly gets its IP address and routing informations via DHCP, just like the other device

Any idea?

---

They are all in the same net

- 192.168.1.152 cm7
- 192.168.1.156 cm10
- 192.168.1.169 osx
- 192.168.1.1 router

Investigating further I've noticed it fails to connect to my laptop (running OSX), but can successfully ping both the router (obviously) and the other android device.
*(I'd stress that the other android device successfully connects to the laptop, instead)*

`logcat` didn't provide any useful info:

- ping returned "destination unreachable", and didn't log anything (even at Verbose level)
- browser just returned a useless `E/Tab     ( 8901): onReceivedError -6 http://192.168.1.169:8888/ The connection to the server was unsuccessful.`
- vlc remote reported that it found two computers `I/*** bonjour ***( 8801): dbg: *** Added Computer [Palace of the Nine Moons] on 192.168.1.169
  I/*** bonjour ***( 8801): dbg: *** Added Computer [Andalù IV] on 192.168.1.170`
  , but nothing else

---

Strangely, if I turn on the wifi on OSX, they detect it: they only have problems reaching the ethernet, for some reason that I still totally miss (yes, not even cm10 can't access it any more).

Disabling the firewall didn't work, but unless someone has a brilliant idea, I'd be inclined into thinking that is either OSX or the router that is going mad, rather than android.

I'll leave this open, though, since I really can't yet rule out android being crazy.

Comment: Could you please give a few more details on what's working ("everything else") and what's not (LAN)? Both terms are quite vague. Can you e.g. surf the web with a browser, can the apps access their web sources? Where's the border between "LAN" and "everything else"?

Comment: @Izzy better now?

Comment: Yepp, now it's clear. So it connects and gets set up via DHCP, but the network isn't accessible. Have you checked `logcat` for errors? Running CM7 (Gingerbread), you could use any Logcat app from Google Play, or `adb logcat` when connected to your PC via USB. That should give you some clues at least.

Comment: What IP address does it get? If it gets an address not in 192.168.1.xxx, that would explain why it can't access that network.

Comment: What AP is that? Is the option "devices may connect to other devices" enabled?

Comment: @DanHulme they are most definitely in the same net, yes

Comment: @ott-- I've no idea what that option is, where can I find it?

Comment: You need to type of your AP before I can tell you where to look for it.

Comment: @ott-- oh sure you meant in the AP. It's a D-Link DSL-2640R, but I don't think there is such an option. And, remember that some devices are able to connect (see the edited version of my post).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, CM7 includes the tcpdump utility to record network traffic (or just install it if it doesn't). You can use it to create a dump (tcpdump -i IFACENAME -w /sdcard/dump.pcap), transfer it to your PC and load it into Wireshark (you can find out the correct IFACENAME by executing `route`, or `cat /proc/net/dev`). Looking at the raw traffic in Wireshark may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: @ce4 - or just firing up Wireshark on the Mac in promiscuous mode.

Comment: @Lohoris - I'm with ott in thinking it's a setting on your router. [Look for DMZ settings](http://www.scribd.com/doc/48602796/60/DMZ-and-Firewall-Setup), any advanced IP or protocol routing, or any QoS settings that could be affecting that 192.168.1.152 IP.